# has_one association selecting specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have `user` model which `has_one` association with `user_profile`

And I want to select name field from user_profile instead of `user_profile`.*

I have tried,

```
user = User.first
user.user_profile.select(:name)
```

But this is not working.any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

It seems, that rails handles the other direction and one-to-one connections differently. You have two options:

1) Define the selected attributes in the association, it will always select those

`has_one :user_profile, :select => [:name, :id]`

2) Define a specific find in your model, where you can add `select`, like this:

```
def my_profile
  UserProfile.find(self.user_profile_id)
end

....

my_profile.select(:name)
```

**ORIGINAL:**

In case of `has_many` direction, it works:

I've tried your method in my code, like:

```
= User.find("admin").article.select(:title).to_sql
```

It returns the correct sql:

```
SELECT title 
FROM "articles"
WHERE "articles"."user_id" = 1364
```

Comment: In your case, user have has_many relationship with articles I guess. And in mycase I have user which has_one with user_profile.